# How can I remove a phrase from a string but not the individual words

Tags: python

**It is resolved**, that was a lack of attention on my part. `report = report.replace('contact sales', '')` works since `replace` returns the new string and does not alter the original.

I want to remove some

> contact sales

instances from a string but I do not want to remove

> contact

or

> sales

if they exist individually.

I tried: `report.replace('contact sales', '')` but it did not work. It detects the phrase but does not remove it. How do I get this done?

Comment: Your replace should work, could you include the code in your question?

Comment: Please post a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Its possible you're not assigning the result? `report = report.replace(...)`

Comment: @costaparas is likely right. `replace` does not change the variable, you need to reassign it. `report = report.replace('contact sales', '')`

Comment: Rather than updating your question to indicate that it is resolved, accept the answer that resolved it for you.

Comment: it is better to open a terminal and type the commands to see what it returns. This way you could ensure that in place replacement or a new string is returned

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get this done by redefining the variable when replacing instances.

For example:

```
report = report.replace('contact sales', '')
```

The logic behind it is that the replace() function does not modify the string in place, it creates a new string with the replaced instances. That's why you need to redefine it.